# How to sort an array of objects in Java in field level for grade comparison?

Tags: java, string, sorting, compare

In Java,

```
Class StudentProgress
{
        String Name;
        String Grade;
        /* CTOR goes here */
}

main class
{
     main method()
     {
         StudentProgress arrayofObjects[100000];
     }
}
```

If the Grades are like D-,C-,B-,A-,A,B,C,D,A+,B+,C+,D+. I need to sort these objects how can I do it efficiently 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Must it be an array? May it be a `List`?

Comment: This is homework question, am I right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best approach is to make your class implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). Something like this will work:

```
public class StudentProgress implements Comparable<StudentProgress> {

    String name;
    String grade;
    char baseGrade;    // Just the letter
    int gradeModifier; // -1 0 or +1 - done to make sorting easier

    public StudentProgress( String name, String grade ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
        // Extract the grade parts for use when comparing
        baseGrade = grade.charAt( 0 );
        gradeModifier = grade.length() == 1 ? 0 : Integer.parseInt( grade.charAt( 1 ) + "1" );
    }

    public int compareTo( StudentProgress o ) {
        return baseGrade == o.baseGrade ? gradeModifier - o.gradeModifier : baseGrade - o.baseGrade;
    }
}
```

Then to sort, you simply use the [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) method:

```
StudentProgress[] array = ...;
Arrays.sort(array);
```

If you don't want your class to implement this interface, you can provide a stand-alone `Comparator` to the sort call

Answer (score 3):

The classes you are looking for is, Comparable and Comparator.

This tutorial will guide you, http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Good luck!